# Is it possible to create a pre-compiler plugin for Java 8?

Tags: java, regex, plugins, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

#### Some background:

I enjoy doing [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) challenges in Java, where the goal is to do a certain task in as few bytes/characters as possible. As a simply example: checking if an integer `n` is a prime with an as short as possible (lambda) function is **47 bytes**:

```
n->{for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n>1;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY9Ba4NAEIXv@RWPQEGRGO0xavoLmkvoqRSyrms6ic7K7hoowd9uJ6mHXoaZeW8e31zUTW3sYPjSXGfdKe/xrojvK4A4GNcqbXB4jEBtbWcUo41EAseFbKeVFB9UII0DGBVm3uzvrXVPE1WvBZVccMUvlCRl/pbt5NCZMDoG7/NimoHiETKMdSchS9bNUoNeSKJjcMTnzy@o@A/jfzaorJBnmTRJEj9lAW8jTgUyjrHd4sMb2NGhU33dKAQL/W30VVw40QnkoTA46s1uOQeOPz6YPrVjSEXhEFGyxnr5d5p/AQ)

Code-golf answers are usually very unreadable, lacking white-spaces and new-lines, only using single-character variable, method and class names, might give compiler warnings, etc. But we don't care about none of that as long as it's as short as possible in code-golfing.

So, that's code-golfing in a nutshell. Although I've already answered [loads of code-golfing challenges in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen?tab=answers&sort=votes), there is one function that I wish Java had on multiple occasions: Using the capture group of a regex for something similar to JavaScript or Retina.

For example, it would be great if these things would be possible in Java:
**A**:

```
// Converting the capture group to an Integer:
s->n->s.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+)",new Integer("$1")+n+"")
// i.e. "test123" & 7 will become 130 (123 + 7)

// Getting the length of a capture group:
s->s.replaceAll("(\\D*(\\d+))",new Integer("$2")+"$1".length()+"")
// i.e. "test123" will become 130 (123 + the length of "test123")

// Getting a character or substring of a capture group:
s->s.replaceAll(".(.+)",s+"$1".charAt(0))
// i.e. "test" will become "teste" ("test" + "est".charAt(0))
```

Of course these things above are possible with some small modifications:
**B**:

```
s->n->new Integer(s.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+)","$1"))+n+""
s->new Integer(s.replaceAll("(\\D*(\\d+))","$2"))+s.replaceAll("(\\D*(\\d+))","$1").length()+""
s->s.replaceAll(".(.+)",s)+s.replaceAll(".(.+)","$1").charAt(0)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##vZRLTxsxFIX3/Iorqwu7QwYSFki0RAqUSixYVV01leI4l8mkxjO1PYEoym8Pnth5DORJodlMYvve8/nckxnwIa9lOapB7890KiQ3Bu54qsZHAMZymwoYuCNxYVMZ3xdK2DRT8ffw5esPq1OVHG89c6ssJqiPwR9uNoHDpWvvBGpNVWuaWGMuucCWlJS0298@03a7FzFyrPARQjUln@qERSoihLnaLx@J16rgrUJsRp3heb6AdxhhEIfuUrsqRpdqr5xpOGdKgFiiSmyfsre5NGe4Wrn/xstXeWYMLNp@xDm0ShgAy8/bOMUmr2IalzMx3hTR57pl6Sn7B0uud0m9vHtY95deECyjkRdd6RgCyjBLe/Dg/nbUC/76zXVi2Him6ZcgVXlh63AJxKKx9cYZ8e6lyvq9hts792tWj8bB2lCt0RTSuhM85nkuR9S3Y6u/Gmw@j/SekvrZKYnxb8Glob6aMTg5gZunHIXF3gW4E0AdSHTOQp2TGxmLD3FW2Dh3wlYqSjq8AwkfItg@wn0mZfa4RLoAEoX2c3WUBsdbO94qkWntMOb3KkzZ0Qmtabe@xU9f0eo489wu75WVrWDHwuIX/ix6TmbPCQhuRZ/ePAnMy9wAsoXvazRvtM40ZEIUGntVZly0fm9Yj7qma9h/lbHXEdsSp@6q5s78bI9J93/FpHtwTK4qzl9VLv0RoejuH4o90PaKQGX2uwcvNg6@rMfF6ElH7DfWFy@XWReg5QMiICVT9U2@0Zh3i4k4OCbXlVlcf3hMPCHGCdo7NIYnSNk@mdmDs6ScHE2m02c)

#### Question itself:

Now my question: Is it possible to create a plugin that modifies the compiler code, so the `replaceAll` with capture groups displayed at **A** above would be modified to those displayed at **B**. Basically creating a plugin/library/compiler-flags or anything that modifies the pre-compiled code when capture groups are used in `String#replaceAll` or `String#replaceFirst` specifically.

PS: I'm not sure yet whether the code at **A** is how I want it in the end, maybe I'll make it more like JavaScript (or Retina) instead:

```
// Syntax used above at A:
s->s.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+)","$1".length()+"")
// JavaScript syntax alternative:
s->s.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+)",a->a.length()+"") // a-> is the capture group 1
// Retina syntax alternative:
s->s.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d+)",new Integer("$#1")+"") // $#1 is the length of capture group 1
```

but that's irrelevant for the question itself: how to create a pre-compile plugin doing a certain modification to the `String#replaceAll(...,"$#")` or `String#replaceFirst(...,"$#")` parts of the code. (And whether this is even possible to begin with.)

Comment: The 2nd "Try it online" link throws errors

Comment: @c0der I know, that's the point. I currently catch the error of the code I want to work with this pre-compiler plugin, and use the longer work-around versions instead to give the results. As you can see the errors are catched and printed to STDOUT, not uncaught and thrown at STDERR (debug-window on TIO).

Answer (score 0):

I never visited Code Golf but I think , you need a Transpiler. Google for "Building Transpiler". You can also approach for Compiler or Interpreter. Use ANTLR to specify A and B grammars OR hardcode it in java then map them according to lexer and parser. This is not difficult but i think lengthy process for an individual because you need to map everything offered by B in A.